# Epoxide with solvent vs with water

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, solvents

[image: Reaction of 2‐bromo‐1‐phenylethan‐1‐one with sodium borohydride in methanol]

The answer given is an epoxide.

But is an epoxide stable at room temperature?
And also epoxides tend to open in presence of water. Even if methyl alcohol is treated as a solvent, then too methyl alcohol is more acidic than water. Then if in water we expect the alpha-bromide alcohol, then why not in methyl alcohol?

Comment: Epoxides are a lot more stable than you seem to think, they do not routinely open in water. The product in this case is styrene oxide which is widely commercially available, stable in MeOH solution, and may be distilled at atmosphere pressure.

Comment: Would we get the same product at room temperature with water?

Comment: The starting material is poorly soluble in water, I doubt you would get any reaction unless you addded a phase transfer catalyst